# Show that the matrices S and T are similar.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let m ≤ n, and A ∈ M$_{m,n}$(F) and B ∈ M$_{n,m}$(F).

$S$ = $\begin{bmatrix}AB & 0_{m,n}\\B & 0_{n,n}\end{bmatrix}$ and $T$ = $\begin{bmatrix}0_{m,m} & 0_{m,n}\\B & BA\end{bmatrix}$

If there exists a $P$ ∈ GL$_{m+n}(F)$ such that $S$ = $P$ $T$ $P^{-1}$, then $S$ and $T$ are similar.

I have tried getting the determinant and trace and characteristic polynomial but I don't think the converse works.

But how do I show that there exists a P?

Comment: Use $\lambda$-matrix theory.

Answer (score 1):

If you write $SP=PT$ you can simply solve for $P\in \mathsf{GL}$ (in blocks) and obtain
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{pmatrix}
I_m & A\\ 0 & I_n
\end{pmatrix}. 
\end{equation}